# How to calculate the strike for a sticky delta volatility curve

Tags: volatility-smile

I am sourcing the implied volatility for pricing the option. I am getting the volatility against delta but not the strike amount for those. How do I convert the delta into the strike to find the right volatility from the curve?

Comment: FX? If so, check out the paper [FX Volatility smile construction](https://mathfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/CPQF_Arbeits20_neu2.pdf) by Uwe Wystup and Dmitri Reiswich.  For many pairs you will need a root finder (all pairs where delta is premium included). However, it may be worth to check with your data provider, frequently you can retrieve it directly by strike as well.

Comment: Thanks. I wish to use for FX and CM primarily. I will go through this for FX. Any suggestion for CM?

Comment: Commodity is usually black76. There is a direct closed form solution for Strike similar to FX (there is no such complication as premium included). Use the formula for delta, and solve for K.

Comment: Thanks for quick help. Will try above method.